# How to use inline for-loop to replace substrings?

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to replace substrings to nothing. For example, I want to convert `£1,000.90` to `1000.90` i.e. simply replace `'£'` and '`,'` with nothing.
And I thought I will do this using the inline `for` loop.

```
s = '£1,000.90'
replaceStrings = ['£', ',']
s = (s.replace(x, '') for x in replaceStrings)
print(s)
```

But it doesn't work.
I find many alternatives to get this done, but I thought I'll try with the inline `for` loop.

Edit:
The answers are interesting. What is the simplest of way of replacing a list of characters to something else. Same example mentioned below. I have a list in `replaceStrings`. They must be removed/replaced with Empty/`x` from the source string `s`.

```
s = '£1,000.90'
replaceStrings = ['£', ',']
```

Comment: You can't do this with an iterator. That returns a separate result for each element of `replaceStrings`, it doesn't combine them. Use an ordinary loop.

Comment: Use `re.sub()` if you want to replace multiple strings with the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that in Python, the "inline for loop" is called a _generator expression_ (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: @Barmar I'd say this is a working solution with an iterator: `*_, s = ((s := s.replace(x, '')) for x in replaceStrings)`

Comment: @superbrain Can you give a more detailed explanation of this line? It includes a lot of features I have not learned yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(s.replace(x, '') for x in replaceStrings)` creates a generator which yields versions of `s` with strings from `replaceStrings` removed. Clearly this isn't what you want.

This is a perfect example of when [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) would be a good option:

```
import re

s = '£1,000.90'
s = re.sub('£|,', '', s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `translate`.

```
>>> s.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, replaceStrings)))
'1000.90'
```

Or if `replaceStrings` were a string (`'£,'`):

```
>>> s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', replaceStrings))
'1000.90'
```

But the best option might be the loop:

```
for c in replaceStrings:
    s = s.replace(c, '')
```

Btw, `replaceStrings` seems like a bad name for a "list of *characters*" that you want to *remove*. Also, a *list* of characters is a string thing in Python. Could just use a *string* then.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org//3/library/re.html#re.sub) like so:

```
import re
s = '£1,000,000.90'
s = re.sub(r'[£,]', '', s)
print(s)
# 1000000.90
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"".join([i for i in s if i not in(",","£")])
```

Hope this aswers your question

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using creates a generator which, when iterated over, will do the replacements. But then, the replacement don't affect `s`.

The comment suggesting you use an ordinary `for` loop is correct. You can write that in one line if you insist:

```
for x in replaceStrings: s = s.replace(x, '')
```

If you really want to abuse the generator expression, and are using Python 3.8 or later where the walrus operator `:=` is supported, you can also do it like this:

```
all((s := s.replace(x, '')) for x in replaceStrings)
```

Here `all` is the built-in function that returns `True` if all items in an iterable object are truthy. It exits and returns `False` if it sees a falsy item.  This does have the minor advantage that it will stop if `s` ever becomes empty, which would mean all other replace operations are unnecessary. Normally, though, this kind of tomfoolery would be a code smell, and your use case doesn't need this behavior.

Comment: They're saving all the replacements in `s`.

Comment: No, they're storing a generator in `s`. They never iterate over it, so none of the replacements are made.